# Shortcut for hide/show preview in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

**Problem**

Typing in a layout seems like hanging sometimes when the preview is opened. So I hide the preview when editing the layout and see the preview after completion. I have to switch to the mouse for that. This is one of the reasons to hold the mouse (which I want to ignore).

**Question**

Is there a standard shortcut for showing/hiding the preview tab in layout mode instead of clicking on the preview? Or does Android Studio not provide shortcut for this?

Please note I am aware that we can switch in design & text mode by the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>left/right arrow</kbd>, but I am finding a shortcut for controlling the preview tab.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. You can [configure custom keymaps](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts#configure_custom_keymaps)

- You can choose from a number of preset keymaps or modify a preset keymap to create a new custom keymap in the keymap settings for Android Studio.

> Click on files->Settings -> key-map then search **"preview"**

then click on "preview" and the click on Add keyboard short

Like below image

[image]

Comment: Hello Nilesh, nice to see you again. Bro so there is not any standard way. Cool, I will add custom shortcut.

Comment: @Khemraj i don't think there is standard way